# How do I use airflow's FileSensor glob matching to find a file with a file with a specific string in its name and a set file extension e.g .txt/.csv?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-taskflow

I need to find a file being moved into a folder that has a specific name and also the .txt extension. I have seen both of these examples used:

```
file_check = FileSensor(
  task_id='check_file',
  filepath='filepath/to/folder/*.txt'
)
```

And

```
file_check = FileSensor(
  task_id='file_check',
  filepath='filepath/to/folder/example_file*'
)
```

How can you find a file with a specific string in its name e.g. "example_file" for "example_file_2023-01-01.txt" and a .txt/csv file extension?

Will either of these work?

```
file_check = FileSensor(
  task_id='file_check',
  filepath='filepath/to/folder/example_file**.txt'
)
```

```
file_check = FileSensor(
  task_id='file_check',
  filepath='filepath/to/folder/example_file*.txt'
)
```

I am unsure if airflow's glob matching permits ** or an AND condition and if the glob matching can be used in this way.

Thanks for your help!